# increment constructor with medhod

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

> Create a class `Student` which is derived from the class `Person` from
>   homework 1.  The class has the member variables:
>
> `facultyNumber`  - a
>   String, which will be initialized to value `"426789XX"` where the XX is
>   the serial number of the object created in the program (if the program
>   has created 3 objects, the value of XX respectively will be - 00, 01
>   and 02).
>
> `notes` – an array of 20 int values in the interval [2,6]. The
>   elements of the array will be initialized with the values 1.
>
> and the methods:
>
> `void takeExam(int index, int note)` - assign  the value note 
>   to the element in position index
>
> `void failExam(int index)` – assign 
>   the value 2 to the element in position index
>
> `public String toString ()`
>   -   convert the Student to String

i have some thing like this homework and where i m doing mistake i dont know little help i m completely newbie for java

```
public class Student extends Person {
    Student() {
        facultyNumber = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(facultyNumber) + 1);
        System.out.print(" Faculty Number: ");
        System.out.print(facultyNumber);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(" Enter notes: ");
        int notes = in.nextInt();
    }

    Student(String name, int age, String facultyNumber, int notes) {
        super(name, age);
    }

    String facultyNumber = "42678900";
    int[] notes ={1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};

    void takeExam(int index, int note) {}
    void failExam(int index){ Arrays.fill(notes, 2); }
    public String toString () {
        return "name: " + name + " age: " + age + " Faculty Number: " + facultyNumber +" notes: " + notes ;
    }
}
```

i think i should do some counting for chance faculty no increment but i dont know how to start anybody can help step by step.

Comment: This code looks a bit messy/random, what you put in Student() should go in a main(), why don't you start from an empty file adding progressively  little pieces of functionality and testing that everything works at each step?

Comment: Also, http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

Well, a homework question.

```
public class Student extends Person {
    private static final int VALUE_EXAM_FAIL = 2;
    private String facultyNumber = "426789XX";
    private int[] notes = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};

    //a new object is instantiated from outside this class, 
    //therefore they have to tell this constructor the facultyNumber (or you use a static facultyNumber)
    public Student(int facultyNumber) {
        this.facultyNumber = this.facultyNumber.replace("XX", String.valueOf(facultyNumber)); //think about problems if facultyNumber only has 1 digit.
    }

    public Student(String name, int age, int facultyNumber, int[] notes) {
        super(name, age); //what is this?
        this(facultyNumber); //and this?
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    public void takeExam(int index, int note) { notes[index] = note; } //what happens here if index = -1 or 99?
    public void failExam(int index) { notes[index] = VALUE_EXAM_FAIL; }
    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return "class: " + this.getClass.getSimpleName() 
           + " name: " + this.name 
           + " age: " + this.age 
           + " Faculty Number: " + this.facultyNumber 
           + " notes: " + this.notes ; //this could be nicer!
    }
}
```

Use access modifiers like public/private!
This should help you getting started. Think about: should I read from the console here in this class? If yes, how? If no, why not?

Comment: `this(facultyNumber);` for this giving error i dont know why, my main working correctly

Comment: Note that Strings are immutable in Java and just calling replace() will not change anything.

Comment: oops, will edit! Believe me, it is not the first time I did this -.-

Comment: @ivaylo ivaylov not anylonger :) I believe you'll get it if you compare the constructors in detail.

Comment: :) thanks for motivation, thank by the way for help beginning for start

Comment: `public void takeExam(int index,......` like this but  i have main `Student s[]= new Student[3];` after for and print students my question how can i use this index for Student input or not :) ?

Comment: I would not instantiate 3 Students at once, but only if you need them. when you need them you should know how many you've got already, There is also a length-function for arrays, telling you how large the array is.

Answer (score 0):

i solve my problem like this its working

```
import java.util.*;
public class Student extends Person {
    private static final int VALUE_EXAM_FAIL = 2;
    private String facultyNumber = "426789XX";
    private int[] notes = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
    static int index = 0;
    private int ind;

Student(){
    ind = index;
    index++;
    this.facultyNumber = this.facultyNumber.replace("XX", String.format("%02d", ind));
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean goodinput = false;
    int num = 0;
    do {
        try {
            goodinput = true;
            System.out.print("Notes [2,6]:");
            num = notes[ind] = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
            System.out.println(num);
            if ((num < 2) || (num > 6)) {
                System.out.println("Input not between 2 and 6, try again.");
                goodinput = false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Input is not an integer, try again.");
            goodinput = false;
        }
    } while (!goodinput);

}
public Student(String name, int age, int facultyNumber, int[] notes) {
    super(name, age);
    this.facultyNumber = Integer.toString(facultyNumber);
    this.notes = notes;
}
public void takeExam(int index, int note) { notes[ind] = note;  }
public void failExam(int index) { notes[ind] = VALUE_EXAM_FAIL; }
@Override
public String toString () {
    return  super.toString() + " Faculty Number: " +  this.facultyNumber
            + " notes: " + this.notes[ind]+ " " + ind;
}
}
```